# Paypal Sandbox IPN item_name is empty

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-ipn

I'm trying to pass item_name and item_number through Paypal ExpressCheckout and to receive them with Paypal IPN(in PHP).

In SetExpressCheckout I set item_name and item_number like this:

rest if SEC query string +

```
."L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME0=". urlencode($product_label). "&" .
"L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NUMBER0=". urlencode( $product_id );
```

The problems comes when Paypal sends me back ipn from payments made, but the item_name and item_number variables are empty. Those two fields are not empty when I make GetExpressCheckoutDetails call ( as L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME0 and L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NUMBER0 ).

I don't know if I explained well my problem but I hope you'll understand my tiredness
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you're including the item details in SetExpressCheckout but then you're not including them in DoExpressCheckoutPayment.  If you don't include them in DECP they won't be included in the actual payment, so they won't be returned in IPN or show up in transaction details.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!
But, when I set L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME0=something it returns me in IPN "item_name1". I want to use the same ipn for both buynow button and express checkout, but in buynow it returns me "item_name" field. Is it possible to return the same field name for both payment methods?

Comment: The buy now buttons are associated with a single item. As such, it only includes a single item's data in the IPN and doesn't need an array, so it doesn't use 1,2,3, etc.  You can setup your IPN script to handle both pretty easily,though.